# Stimulsoft options to define actions loaded with incorrect route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft report on a .net core application include area, when I define report actions in StiNetCoreDesignerOptions method and run application actions called with incorrect route like this:

```
[area]/[action]/[controller]
```

in my view:

```
@Html.StiNetCoreDesigner(new StiNetCoreDesignerOptions()
{
    Actions =
    {
        GetReport ="GetReport",
        PreviewReport = "PreviewReport",
        DesignerEvent = "DesignerEvent",
    }
})
```

and in my controller:

```
[Area(AreaConstants.Automation)]
[Route("[area]/letter-print/[action]")]
public class LetterPrintController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetReport()
    {
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "wwwroot/Reports/TwoSimpleLists.mrt"));

        return StiNetCoreDesigner.GetReportResult(this, report);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult PreviewReport()
    {
        var data = new DataSet("Demo");
        data.ReadXml(StiNetCoreHelper.MapPath(this, "wwwroot/Reports/Data/Demo.xml"));

        StiReport report = StiNetCoreDesigner.GetActionReportObject(this);
        report.RegData(data);

        return StiNetCoreDesigner.PreviewReportResult(this, report);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DesignerEvent()
    {
        return StiNetCoreDesigner.DesignerEventResult(this);
    }
}
```

finally get this error:

```
GET https://localhost:44379/Automation/DesignerEvent/LetterPrint?stiweb_component=Designer&stiweb_action=Resource&stiweb_cachemode=cache&stiweb_version=2019.3.5&stiweb_data=DesignerScripts net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Uncaught ReferenceError: StiMobileDesigner is not defined
```